# How do i know what values have been changed in the table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a Html Table which consists of rows that were generated dynamically (from PHP) 
and each row  conatins the select box and textbox with the  values.
Now how do i know which row has been changed (i mean Select box and textbox).
Iam looking to have a list of  (1,3,5,7) rows that have been changed so that 
i can pass them to the hidden and retrive in php

```
 ("#tb11").change(function(){
  //Code 

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor object for changes. Give the input's (I'm assuming they are inputs) a class of `monitor` and run

```
$(".monitor").bind("keyup", function(event){ /* Code */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

That will give you the index of the row, which has been changed

```
(function() {
  $("table").change(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).closest("tr").index());
  });
})();​
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code:

```
$("#tb11 input").change(function(){
      // Gets the parent row of the item that has been changed and adds a class of changed
      $(this).parent().parent().addclass('changed'); 
});
```

You will need to give each row a unique id number, and use the following code to handle the submission:

```
function submitForm() {
    $('.changed').each(function () {
        // Will loop through each row that has been changed and post a value based on the id attribute
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
        // post the value of your row id to php
        $.post('myurl.php?rowId='+rowId, function(data) {
            //callback method for succesfull post
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, are you saying the user should do a post for each changed row?  Seems unlikely they would want to do that, instead your example could just say collect the rows into an array?